# lib/UI/jquery/assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js WHAT IS ITS PURPOSE?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, json.net

I am completely new to coding and I am just gaining some insight and investigating code that I  have in my cell phone and computer and asking questions about it in order to better understand the function of it.

I am just wondering what this specific code's function would be in a real life situation. I have the entire thread if needed-I think it is google's code-I will just post part of it below.

```
Before(n,r.firstChild)},abort:function(){n&&n.onload(t,!0)}}}});var On=[],Bn=/(=)\?(?=&|$)|\?\?/;b.ajaxSetup({jsonp:"callback",jsonpCallback:function(){var e=On.pop()||b.expando+"_"+vn++;return this[e]=!0,e}}),b.ajaxPrefilter("json jsonp",function(n,r,i){var o,a,s,u=n.jsonp!==!1&&(Bn.test(n.url)?"url":"string"==typeof n.data&&!(n.contentType||"").indexOf("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")&&Bn.test(n.data)&&"data");return u||"jsonp"===n.dataTypes[0]?(o=n.jsonpCallback=b.isFunction(n.jsonpCallback)?n.jsonpCallback():n.jsonpCallback,u?n[u]=n[u].replace(Bn,"$1"+o):n.jsonp!==!1&&(n.url+=(bn.test(n.url)?"&":"?")+n.jsonp+"="+o),n.converters["script json"]=function(){return s||b.error(o+" was not called"),s[0]},n.dataTypes[0]="json",a=e[o],e[o]=function(){s=arguments},i.always(function(){e[o]=a,n[o]&&(n.jsonpCallback=r.jsonpCallback,On.push(o)),s&&b.isFunction(a)&&a(s[0]),s=a=t}),"script"):t});var Pn,Rn,Wn=0,$n=e.ActiveXObject&&function(){var e;for(e in Pn)Pn[e](t,!0)};function In(){try{return new e.XMLHttpRequest}catch(t){}}function zn(){try{return new e.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(t){}}b.ajaxSettings.xhr=e.ActiveXObject?function(){return!this.isLocal&&In()||zn()}:In,Rn=b.ajaxSettings.xhr(),b.support.cors=!!Rn&&"withCredentials"in Rn,Rn=b.support.ajax=!!Rn,Rn&&b.ajaxTransport(function(n){if(!n.crossDomain||b.support.cors){var r;return{send:function(i,o){var a,s,u=n.xhr();if(n.username?u.open(n.type,n.url,n.async,n.username,n.password):u.open(n.type,n.url,n.async),n.xhrFields)for(s in n.xhrFields)u[s]=n.xhrFields[s];n.mimeType&&u.overrideMimeType&&u.overrideMimeType(n.mimeType),n.crossDomain||i["X-Requested-With"]||(i["X-Requested-With"]="XMLHttpRequest");try{for(s in i)u.setRequestHeader(s,i[s])}catch(l){}u.send(n.hasContent&&n.data||null),r=function(e,i){var s,l,c,p;try{if(r&&(i||4===u.readyState))if(r=t,a&&(u.onreadystatechange=b.noop,$n&&delete Pn[a]),i)4!==u.readyState&&u.abort();else{p={},s=u.status,l=u.getAllResponseHeaders(),"string"==typeof u.responseText&&(p.text=u.responseText);try{c=u.statusText}catch(f){c=""}s||!n.isLocal||n.crossDomain?1223===s&&(s=204):s=p.text?200:404}}catch(d){i||o(-1,d)}p&&o(s,c,p,l)},n.async?4===u.readyState?setTimeout(r):(a=++Wn,$n&&(Pn||(Pn={},b(e).unload($n)),Pn[a]=r),u.onreadystatechange=r):r()},abort:function(){r&&r(t,!0)}}}});var Xn,Un,Vn=/^(?:toggle|show|hide)$/,Yn=RegExp("^(?:([+-])=|)("+x+")([a-z%]*)$","i"),Jn=/queueHooks$/,Gn=[nr],Qn={"*":[function(e,t){var n,r,i=this.createTween(e,t),o=Yn.exec(t),a=i.cur(),s=+a||0,u=1,l=20;if(o){if(n=+o[2],r=o[3]||(b.cssNumber[e]?"":"px"),"px"!==r&&s){s=b.css(i.elem,e,!0)||n||1;do u=u||".5",s/=u,b.style(i.elem,e,s+r);while(u!==(u=i.cur()/a)&&1!==u&&--l)}i.unit=r,i.start=s,i.end=o[1]?s+(o[1]+1)*n:n}return i}]};function Kn(){return setTimeout(function(){Xn=t}),Xn=b.now()}function Zn(e,t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=(Qn[t]||[]).concat(Qn["*"]),i=0,o=r.length;for(;o>i;i++)if(r[i].call(e,t,n))return})}function er(e,t,n){var r,i,o=0,a=Gn.length,s=b.Deferred().always(function(){delete u.elem}),u=function(){if(i)return!1;var t=Xn||Kn(),n=Math.max(0,l.startTime+l.duration-t),r=n/l.duration||0,o=1-r,a=0,u=l.tweens.length;for(;u>a;a++)l.tweens[a].run(o);return s.notifyWith(e,[l,o,n]),1>o&&u?n:(s.resolveWith(e,[l]),!1)},l=s.promise({elem:e,props:b.extend({},t),opts:b.extend(!0,{specialEasing:{}},n),originalProperties:t,originalOptions:n,startTime:Xn||Kn(),duration:n.duration,tweens:[],createTween:function(t,n){var r=b.Tween(e,l.opts,t,n,l.opts.specialEasing[t]||l.opts.easing);return l.tweens.push(r),r},stop:function(t){var n=0,r=t?l.tweens.length:0;if(i)return this;for(i=!0;r>n;n++)l.tweens[n].run(1);return t?s.resolveWith(e,[l,t]):s.rejectWith(e,[l,t]),this}}),c=l.props;for(tr(c,l.opts.specialEasing);a>o;o++)if(r=Gn[o].call(l,e,c,l.opts))return r;return Zn(l,c),b.isFunction(l.opts.start)&&l.opts.start.call(e,l),b.fx.timer(b.extend(u,{elem:e,anim:l,queue:l.opts.queue})),l.progress(l.opts.progress).done(l.opts.done,l.opts.complete).fail(l.opts.fail).always(l.opts.always)}function tr(e,t){var n,r,i,o,a;for(i in e)if(r=b.camelCase(i),o=t[r],n=e[i],b.isArray(n)&&(o=n[1],n=e[i]=n[0]),i!==r&&(e[r]=n,delete e[i]),a=b.cssHooks[r],a&&"expand"in a){n=a.expand(n),delete e[r];for(i in n)i in e||(e[i]=n[i],t[i]=o)}else t[r]=o}b.Animation=b.extend(er,{tweener:function(e,t){b.isFunction(e)?(t=e,e=["*"]):e=e.split(" ");var n,r=0,i=e.length;for(;i>r;r++)n=e[r],Qn[n]=Qn[n]||[],Qn[n].unshift(t)},prefilter:function(e,t){t?Gn.unshift(e):Gn.push(e)}});function nr(e,t,n){var r,i,o,a,s,u,l,c,p,f=this,d=e.style,h={},g=[],m=e.nodeType&&nn(e);n.queue||(c=b._queueHooks(e,"fx"),null==c.unqueued&&(c.unqueued=0,p=c.empty.fire,c.empty.fire=function(){c.unqueued||p()}),c.unqueued++,f.always(function(){f.always(function(){c.unqueued--,b.queue(e,"fx").length||c.empty.fire()})})),1===e.nodeType&&("height"in t||"width"in t)&&(n.overflow=[d.overflow,d.overflowX,d.overflowY],"inline"===b.css(e,"display")&&"none"===b.css(e,"float")&&(b.support.inlineBlockNeedsLayout&&"inline"!==un(e.nodeName)?d.zoom=1:d.display="inline-block")),n.overflow&&(d.overflow="hidden",b.support.shrinkWrapBlocks||f.always(function(){d.overflow=n.overflow[0],d.overflowX=n.overflow[1],d.overflowY=n.overflow[2]}));for(i in t)if(a=t[i],Vn.exec(a)){if(delete t[i],u=u||"toggle"===a,a===(m?"hide":"show"))continue;g.push(i)}if(o=g.length){s=b._data(e,"fxshow")||b._data(e,"fxshow",{}),"hidden"in s&&(m=s.hidden),u&&(s.hidden=!m),m?b(e).show():f.done(function(){b(e).hide()}),f.done(function(){var t;b._removeData(e,"fxshow");for(t in h)b.style(e,t,h[t])});for(i=0;o>i;i++)r=g[i],l=f.createTween(r,m?s[r]:0),h[r]=s[r]||b.style(e,r),r in s||(s[r]=l.start,m&&(l.end=l.start,l.start="width"===r||"height"===r?1:0))}}function rr(e,t,n,r,i){return new rr.prototype.init(e,t,n,r,i)}b.Tween=rr,rr.prototype={constructor:rr,init:function(e,t,n,r,i,o){this.elem=e,this.prop=n,this.easing=i||"swing",this.options=t,this.start=this.now=this.cur(),this.end=r,this.unit=o||(b.cssNumber[n]?"":"px")},cur:function(){var e=rr.propHooks[this.prop];return e&&e.get?e.get(this):rr.propHooks._default.get(this)},run:function(e){var t,n=rr.propHooks[this.prop];return this.pos=t=this.options.duration?b.easing[this.easing](e,this.options.duration*e,0,1,this.options.duration):e,this.now=(this.end-this.start)*t+this.start,this.options.step&&this.options.step.call(this.elem,this.now,this),n&&n.set?n.set(this):rr.propHooks._default.set(this),this}},rr.prototype.init.prototype=rr.prototype,rr.propHooks={_default:{get:function(e){var t;return null==e.elem[e.prop]||e.elem.style&&null!=e.elem.style[e.prop]?(t=b.css(e.elem,e.prop,""),t&&"auto"!==t?t:0):e.elem[e.prop]},set:function(e){b.fx.step[e.prop]?b.fx.step[e.prop](e):e.elem.style&&(null!=e.elem.style[b.cssProps[e.prop]]||b.cssHooks[e.prop])?b.style(e.elem,e.prop,e.now+e.unit):e.elem[e.prop]=e.now}}},rr.propHooks.scrollTop=rr.propHooks.scrollLeft={set:function(e){e.elem.nodeType&&e.elem.parentNode&&(e.elem[e.prop]=e.now)}},b.each(["toggle","show","hide"],function(e,t){var n=b.fn[t];b.fn[t]=function(e,r,i){return null==e||"boolean"==typeof e?n.apply(this,arguments):this.animate(ir(t,!0),e,r,i)}}),b.fn.extend({fadeTo:function(e,t,n,r){return this.filter(nn).css("opacity",0).show().end().animate({opacity:t},e,n,r)},animate:function(e,t,n,r){var i=b.isEmptyObject(e),o=b.speed(t,n,r),a=function(){var t=er(this,b.extend({},e),o);a.finish=function(){t.stop(!0)},(i||b._data(this,"finish"))&&t.stop(!0)};return a.finish=a,i||o.queue===!1?this.each(a):this.queue(o.queue,a)},stop:function(e,n,r){var i=function(e){var t=e.stop;delete e.stop,t(r)};return"string"!=typeof e&&(r=n,n=e,e=t),n&&e!==!1&&this.queue(e||"fx",[]),this.each(function(){var t=!0,n=null!=e&&e+"queueHooks",o=b.timers,a=b._data(this);if(n)a[n]&&a[n].stop&&i(a[n]);else for(n in a)a[n]&&a[n].stop&&Jn.test(n)&&i(a[n]);for(n=o.length;n--;)o[n].elem!==this||null!=e&&o[n].queue!==e||(o[n].anim.stop(r),t=!1,o.splice(n,1));(t||!r)&&b.dequeue(this,e)})},finish:function(e){return e!==!1&&(e=e||"fx"),this.each(function(){var t,n=b._data(this),r=n[e+"queue"],i=n[e+"queueHooks"],o=b.timers,a=r?r.length:0;for(n.finish=!0,b.queue(this,e,[]),i&&i.cur&&i.cur.finish&&i.cur.finish.call(this),t=o.length;t--;)o[t].elem===this&&o[t].queue===e&&(o[t].anim.stop(!0),o.splice(t,1));for(t=0;a>t;t++)r[t]&&r[t].finish&&r[t].finish.call(this);delete n.finish})}});function ir(e,t){var n,r={height:e},i=0;for(t=t?1:0;4>i;i+=2-t)n=Zt[i],r["margin"+n]=r["padding"+n]=e;return t&&(r.opacity=r.width=e),r}b.each({slideDown:ir("show"),slideUp:ir("hide"),slideToggle:ir("toggle"),fadeIn:{opacity:"show"},fadeOut:{opacity:"hide"},fadeToggle:{opacity:"toggle"}},function(e,t){b.fn[e]=function(e,n,r){return this.animate(t,e,n,r)}}),b.speed=function(e,t,n){var r=e&&"object"==typeof e?b.extend({},e):{complete:n||!n&&t||b.isFunction(e)&&e,duration:e,easing:n&&t||t&&!b.isFunction(t)&&t};return r.duration=b.fx.off?0:"number"==typeof r.duration?r.duration:r.duration in b.fx.speeds?b.fx.speeds[r.duration]:b.fx.speeds._default,(null==r.queue||r.queue===!0)&&(r.queue="fx"),r.old=r.complete,r.complete=function(){b.isFunction(r.old)&&r.old.call(this),r.queue&&b.dequeue(this,r.queue)},r},b.easing={linear:function(e){return e},swing:function(e){return.5-Math.cos(e*Math.PI)/2}},b.timers=[],b.fx=rr.prototype.init,b.fx.tick=function(){var e,n=b.timers,r=0;for(Xn=b.now();n.length>r;r++)e=n[r],e()||n[r]!==e||n.splice(r--,1);n.length||b.fx.stop(),Xn=t},b.fx.timer=function(e){e()&&b.timers.push(e)&&b.fx.start()},b.fx.interval=13,b.fx.start=function(){Un||(Un=setInterval(b.fx.tick,b.fx.interval))},b.fx.stop=function(){clearInterval(Un),Un=null},b.fx.speeds={slow:600,fast:200,_default:400},b.fx.step={},b.expr&&b.expr.filters&&(b.expr.filters.animated=function(e){return b.grep(b.timers,function(t){return e===t.elem}).length}),b.fn.offset=function(e){if(arguments.length)return e===t?this:this.each(function(t){b.offset.setOffset(this,e,t)});var n,r,o={top:0,left:0},a=this[0],s=a&&a.ownerDocument;if(s)return n=s.documentElement,b.contains(n,a)?(typeof a.getBoundingClientRect!==i&&(o=a.getBoundingClientRect()),r=or(s),{top:o.top+(r.pageYOffset||n.scrollTop)-(n.clientTop||0),left:o.left+(r.pageXOffset||n.scrollLeft)-(n.clientLeft||0)}):o},b.offset={setOffset:function(e,t,n){var r=b.css(e,"position");"static"===r&&(e.style.position="relative");var i=b(e),o=i.offset(),a=b.css(e,"top"),s=b.css(e,"left"),u=("absolute"===r||"fixed"===r)&&b.inArray("auto",[a,s])>-1,l={},c={},p,f;u?(c=i.position(),p=c.top,f=c.left):(p=parseFloat(a)||0,f=parseFloat(s)||0),b.isFunction(t)&&(t=t.call(e,n,o)),null!=t.top&&(l.top=t.top-o.top+p),null!=t.left&&(l.left=t.left-o.left+f),"using"in t?t.using.call(e,l):i.css(l)}},b.fn.extend({position:function(){if(this[0]){var e,t,n={top:0,left:0},r=this[0];return"fixed"===b.css(r,"position")?t=r.getBoundingClientRect():(e=this.offsetParent(),t=this.offset(),b.nodeName(e[0],"html")||(n=e.offset()),n.top+=b.css(e[0],"borderTopWidth",!0),n.left+=b.css(e[0],"borderLeftWidth",!0)),{top:t.top-n.top-b.css(r,"marginTop",!0),left:t.left-n.left-b.css(r,"marginLeft",!0)}}},offsetParent:function(){return this.map(function(){var e=this.offsetParent||o.documentElement;while(e&&!b.nodeName(e,"html")&&"static"===b.css(e,"position"))e=e.offsetParent;return e||o.documentElement})}}),b.each({scrollLeft:"pageXOffset",scrollTop:"pageYOffset"},function(e,n){var r=/Y/.test(n);b.fn[e]=function(i){return b.access(this,function(e,i,o){var a=or(e);return o===t?a?n in a?a[n]:a.document.documentElement[i]:e[i]:(a?a.scrollTo(r?b(a).scrollLeft():o,r?o:b(a).scrollTop()):e[i]=o,t)},e,i,arguments.length,null)}});function or(e){return b.isWindow(e)?e:9===e.nodeType?e.defaultView||e.parentWindow:!1}b.each({Height:"height",Width:"width"},function(e,n){b.each({padding:"inner"+e,content:n,"":"outer"+e},function(r,i){b.fn[i]=function(i,o){var a=arguments.length&&(r||"boolean"!=typeof i),s=r||(i===!0||o===!0?"margin":"border");return b.access(this,function(n,r,i){var o;return b.isWindow(n)?n.document.documentElement["client"+e]:9===n.nodeType?(o=n.documentElement,Math.max(n.body["scroll"+e],o["scroll"+e],n.body["offset"+e],o["offset"+e],o["client"+e])):i===t?b.css(n,r,s):b.style(n,r,i,s)},n,a?i:t,a,null)}})}),e.jQuery=e.$=b,"function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&define.amd.jQuery&&define("jquery",[],function(){return b})})(window);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a *tutor me on what someone else's code is doing* site. Please take some time to complete the [tour] and read through the [help] pages, particularly [ask] and [mcve], before your next post  here.

Answer (score -1):

That code is the minified jQuery library. Minified code is just shrunken so that it is optimized to run in browsers.

JQuery is a Javascript library to help with coding for front end developers.

You can see the library here... https://jquery.com/

Comment: I think because, your answer actually is useless because the op make an unclear and problematic question . So this type of questions can't get valid answers, at the moment.

Comment: But it isn't useless. I explained that it is minified code and what is the source. The question isn't that bad of a question.